# Having trouble with my python program

Tags: python, math, python-3.4

I'm having a bit of trouble. So, for my assignment, my teacher wants us to read in data and output the data into another file. Now, the data we are reading in are Students name(Line one), and their grades(Line 2). Now, he wants us to read them in, then write them into another file. Write them in two lines. Line one, being the students name, and line two, being their average. Then, write the averages into a list and run the whole list through mean, median, and standard deviation. Here's an example of some data from the file.

```
Aiello,Joseph
88 75 80
Alexander,Charles
90 93 100 98
Cambell,Heather
100 100
Denniston,Nelson
56 70 65
```

So, as you see, it's last name first, separated by a comma, then first. Then, on line two, their grades. He wants us to find the average of them and then write them under the students name. That's the part I'm having trouble on. I know how to find an average. Add the grades up, then divide by the number of grades they got. But how do I put that into python? Can anyone help? Also, I already have a mean, median, standard deviation program. How would I put the averages I get from the first part into a list, then putting the whole list through the mean, median, standard devation program.And back to my original question. Is there anything wrong with what I have so far? Anything I need to add/change? Here's my code.

```
def main():
    input1 = open('StudentGrades.dat', 'r')
    output = open('StudentsAvg', 'w')
    for nextLine in input1:
        output.write(nextLine)
    list1 = nextLine.split()
    count = int(list1[3])
    for p in range(count):
        nextLine = input1.readlin()
        output.write(nextLine)
        list2 = nextLine.split()
        name = int(list2[1])
        grades = list2[2]
        pos = grades.index(grade)
        avg =
```

Comment: Have you tried this code? What do you get?

Comment: Well, it fails at AVG = because I've added nothing to it. I know how to find averages for grades, but how would I put that into python language so it writes it into line two for each person. Grades + grades left / number of grades = Avg. But, how would i convert that into python language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there's a few problems here. The first is that what everything you're reading from the file is a string, not a number. Secondly, you should probably be doing all of this within the same for loop wherein you read the lines. (One more point - use the `with` statement to allow your file objects to be automatically destructed when you're done with them.) So, you could modify your code as follows:

```
def main():
    with open('StudentGrades.dat', 'r') as input1, open('StudentsAvg.txt', 'w') as output:
        counter = 0
        student_name = ''
        for nextLine in input1:
            if counter % 2 == 0:
                student_name = nextLine
            else:
                grades = [int(x) for x in nextLine.split()]
                avg = sum(grades) / len(grades)
                print(student_name, file=output)
                print(str(avg), file=output)

            counter += 1
```

Note that `print(str, file)` is the current, preferred method for writing to a file.

Comment: How do I open the output file that python is putting this data into?

Comment: @Matty You already have. That's what open('StudentsAvg') does.

Comment: Oh. I think I must have made something unclear. I have to read in the data from StudentGrades, then tell python to open a whole new file, save it, and write the data in there. The data in the new File(StudentsAvg.txt) would contain their names(on line 1) and their average(on line two)

Comment: @Matty That is what this code does now. It opens `StudentGrades.dat`, iterates through it, and writes to `StudentsAvg` one line for student name and one line for their average grade for each student name/all grades pairing in the read file. You don't mean that the entirety of `StudentsAvg` should only ever be composed of two lines, do you?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be composed of two lines. What I was wondering was where is the new file that Python creates called StudentsAvg? It reads the data from StudentGrades.dat, and should create a whole new file to store the new data into(output). I'm looking for that file because I need it for the second part. In that file will be the students name, and under their name their average. Then the next student in line three, then their average in line four, and this continues until there are no more students left.

Comment: @Matty The functionality you're talking about is exactly what this code does. The write file will be at the filepath you've provided in your `open` argument: `open('StudentsAvg`)`. If you provide a relative filepath, as you have, the file will created in the same directory as your python script.

Comment: I'm running the program and then trying to open the file StudentsAvg.txt, but it doesn't seem to be present on my computer. StudentGrades.Dat is on my desktop. Where would StudentsAvg.txt be?

Comment: @Matty Unless you've reproduced your code wrong, there should be no possible way that the read and the write files are in different directories. They're both relative paths, so they should be in the same folder.

Comment: I have all the files on my desktop.

Comment: @Matty Then there shouldn't be any possible way that the `StudentsAvg` file isn't being created. Even calling `open('foo.txt', 'w'): pass` will cause the file to be created. Are you sure you've actually typed `open('StudentsAvg.txt')`?

Comment: This is the first two lines of my code: def main():
    with open('StudentGrades.dat' , 'r') as input1, open('StudentsAvg.txt' , 'w') as output: . So, I don't know why it's not creating another file.

Comment: @Matty That should be a single line, not two lines. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Sorry, it is on one line. It's just this spaced it into two. And no, I am not getting a single error. It runs perfectly.

Comment: Try searching your entire computer - this isn't behavior I'm familiar with personally or documentation-wise. In any case, that problem is a totally different problem, and you should ask a separate question about it. As far as I can tell, the problem you posted about has been solved now, so an answer should be selected.

Comment: Thanks for everything. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Matty No problem - sorry I can't point out exactly why the file isn't appearing. I'm sure someone else will be able to help on that front.

Answer (score 0):

Some improvements made to the original code:

```
def averagMarksCalculator():  # Learn to name your functions "Meaningfully"
    # Using with clause - Learn to love it as much as you can!
    with open('StudentGrades.dat') as input1, open('StudentsAvg.txt', 'w') as output:    
    for nextLine in input1:
        strToWrite = nextLine;  # Write student's name
        output.write(nextLine)  # Print student name
        list1 = (input1.readline()).split() # split them into individual strings
        avg = 0 # initialise
        list1 = [int(x) for x in list1]
        avg = sum(list1)/len(list1) 
        output.write("Average marks........"+str(avg)+"\r\n") # avg marks of student
    input1.close()
    output.close()
```

Note that the "\r\n" is to make sure you have a line gap after a student's name and average marks printed on the result file. If you don't need the empty new line as a separator, please use "\r" only.

Comment: How do I open the file that my program is writing the data to?

Comment: Well, like I said, I have to read the data(the data example from the file i showed you) then write the data into an other file(StudentsAvg) and in that file is supposed to be Aiello,Joseph(line one) and under line one, the average of those three grades(line two). And I have to do that for each student. Write their names on line one, and their average on line two, into another file

Comment: That's what I thought I had to do.. So, where does python save this new file with the new data?

Comment: I don't know if I'm not getting something here or what. I understand you're code completely. Thank you for making it much more efficient, by the way. Now, I see that you aren't reading StudentGrades.dat. Any reason for that? And, where does the new file that python creates to write on go? I cannot seem to find it. I have all the files on my desktop, by the way.

Comment: If you are on Windows, copy your data file into C:\PythonXX directory. After that, open Python IDLE and call your function like `>>> averageMarksCalculator()` your result file will be in the same location as the source data file. If you don't understand how to do it, you shouldn't be doing any coding or anything in the first place.